# Android Studio won't import Porcupine project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

When I do File > New > Import Module and select the `porcupinemanager` module, which looks like this:

[image]

It tells me it also needs to import the module called `porcupine` (which i don't know where it is).

I get an empty directory in my Android Studio project:

[image: image2]

This gets added into my `settings.gradle`:

```
include ':app', ':porcupine'
```

I still can't access any of the classes.

In settings.gradle `':porcupine'` is there, even though `porcupine` doesn't exist.

How do I import this library properly? Here's the repo:

https://github.com/Picovoice/Porcupine

Comment: did you add this project in your app gradle like this  `implementation project(':porcupine') `?

Comment: @AnalShah yes, I did.

Comment: You need to check that the Android Plugin Version is the same for both the Project and the imported module.

Answer (score 0):

import the whole project from outside folder or add sdk tools

Comment: What directory?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue is with the Android Plugin Version under Project Structure --> Project might be different to the version of your plugins all used. Once you align them to the same version, you could see all your classes from your imported module.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Depending on what you want to achieve, you have to import either the `Activity` or the `Service` directory.